# Make My Function Keys Work Again?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, function-keys

I have a Toshiba Satellite E55-A5114 (Specs From Toshiba: (http://goo.gl/Yhw3hV)

I just installed Xubuntu 14.10 because my Windows 8 as affected by a virus of some sort or another.  That's really not that important.  What is important is that I'm having problems getting all my Function Keys to behave properly.

Specifically, without holding down Fn, my F2 and F3 keys definitely do not do what they used to in Windows.  Back in Windows, when I pushed F2 the screen would dim.  Likewise, when I hit F3, the screen would brighten.

How do I get this to function properly in my new OS?

Thanks a lot!